# Spring Tools Suite 3.70: EGit - Git Team Provider 4.01 upgrade fails

Tags: egit, spring-tool-suite, jgit

In an attempt to use git hooks via eGit, I'm trying to upgrade eGit to v 4.01.  However, STS 3.70 dependencies depend on older versions, preventing the upgrade.

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Eclipse Git Team Provider 4.0.1.201506240215-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 4.0.1.201506240215-r)
  Software currently installed: Spring Tool Suite 3.7.0.201506290649-RELEASE-e44 (org.springsource.sts.ide 3.7.0.201506290649-RELEASE-e44)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Git Team Provider Core 3.4.2.201412180340-r (org.eclipse.egit.core 3.4.2.201412180340-r)
    Git Team Provider Core 4.0.1.201506240215-r (org.eclipse.egit.core 4.0.1.201506240215-r)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Git Team Provider 4.0.1.201506240215-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 4.0.1.201506240215-r)
    To: org.eclipse.egit.core [4.0.1.201506240215-r]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse GitHub integration with task focused interface 3.4.2.201412180340-r (org.eclipse.mylyn.github.feature.feature.group 3.4.2.201412180340-r)
    To: org.eclipse.mylyn.github.ui [3.4.2.201412180340-r]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Mylyn GitHub Connector UI 3.4.2.201412180340-r (org.eclipse.mylyn.github.ui 3.4.2.201412180340-r)
    To: package org.eclipse.egit.core [3.4.2,3.5.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring Tool Suite 3.7.0.201506290649-RELEASE-e44 (org.springsource.sts.ide 3.7.0.201506290649-RELEASE-e44)
    To: org.springsource.sts.package.feature.group [3.7.0.201506290649-RELEASE-e44]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring Tool Suite Package 3.7.0.201506290649-RELEASE-e44 (org.springsource.sts.package.feature.group 3.7.0.201506290649-RELEASE-e44)
    To: org.eclipse.mylyn.github.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
```

I've only seen unsuccessful approaches to circumvent this so far. Other than starting with a bare Eclipse version and plugging in STS, is there another way?

Perhaps the next version of STS is due out soon?

Comment: The next version of STS (3.7.1) is to be released shortly after Eclipse Mars.1, by the end of September. But in addition to that I could imagine switching the egit inclusion to a mode that makes updating this component more independent of the STS version. Are you okay with a release by end of September? Another option would be to download an early nightly distribution build of STS 3.7.1, which already includes egit 4.0.1 from here: http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/STS/nightly-distributions.html ?

Comment: Can you provide how to switch the egit inclusion?  I've seen other posts which seem to instruct others to do this, but seem too involved to be practical for an entire team. The nightly dist sounds like the way to go and is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: The switch could only be internally inside the STS build. So you would have to wait for the next STS 3.7.1 release anyway - or adopt the nightly build - at the moment. But the switch would make it easier the next time.

Comment: These are perfectly acceptable answers, please feel free to post them as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next version of STS 3.7.1 is to be released shortly after Eclipse Mars.1, by the end of September. That version will include the latest version from Egit.

In addition to that you can consume a nightly build of STS 3.7.1 (from: http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/STS/nightly-distributions.html), which already contains the updated Egit version.

To make it easier to upgrade the Egit components, I also changed the way they are installed into the distribution build. That should make future updates easier.

Hope that helps!!!